# Apache Kafka Zookeeper silently failing to start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I downloaded the file [`kafka_2.11-2.1.0`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.11-2.1.0.tgz) from the Kafka website, unzipped it, and as instructed, ran the command to start the built-in Zookeeper server. But when I do so, nothing happens:

```
$ ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties
$
```

No error is shown, simply nothing happens.

I'm doing this on macOS Mojave.

I tried rebooting. Not sure what else to try, as there's simply no error message to google for. Any ideas?

Comment: `brew install zookeeper` has been working fine for me. Docker works great as well and doesn't clutter the filesystem

Comment: Can you please edit `./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh` and add `set -xv` towards the top (after the shebang), and rerun? Then paste output in question?

Comment: Good idea about actually looking inside the script itself. It's actually empty, so I guess that explains why it's doing nothing. I might try downloading an earlier version of the binaries and see if they have some content in this file.

Comment: Ok, got it working with [kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz). Will drop a note to the team to ask them to fix the kafka_2.11-2.1.0 binaries.

Comment: Hmm. Shouldnt be empty https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  FWIW, Confluent Platform OSS packages more useful utilities for getting started

Comment: It might be a problem with the build or deployment step even if their source file on github contains content

Comment: Yeah, not sure where the Apache build servers are. Did you say you were going to create a JIRA?